# Python - encoding info in a table

Tags: python, assembly, document, encode

I'm processing assembly language source with python.  My main table, driven by opcode, has information about each opcode including number/usage of register operands, size of the operation etc.  It's currently stored as a dict with the opcode as key and a list of indicators as the value.  It works but it's pretty easy to screw up and I won't remember how it works when I have to fix it.  Is there a better way to separate the data from the processing?

```
opdefs={ #operator defs
    #[number of register operands,
    # <for each operand code 1=dest,2=src,3=both,4=overhead>,
    #storage use code:0 for none, 1 for dest, 2 for source
    #operation size(-means call opsizer routine)]
    'cpy2': [2,1,2,0,4], 'cpy1': [2,1,2,0,2], 'cpy4': [2,11,12,0,8],
```

In this, cpy2 has two register operands, the first one is a destination, the second one a source, it has no storage references, and it's 4 bytes long.

The main loop, after tokenizing each line of the file looks like

```
numoperands=opdefs[tokens[0]][0] #numer of operands
for operandnum in range(1,numoperands+1):
    if opdefs[tokens[0]][operandnum]==1: #dest register
        destreg(tokens[operandnum]) #count times register is loaded
```

I wouldn't mind if I was only going to run this once but I figure there has to be a better way to organize or encode this.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use the [`collections.namedtuple` class factory](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.namedtuple) to create a tuple-like object to replace your lists; store your operator codes in a tuple *within* that object:

```
from collections import namedtuple
opdef = namedtuple(opdef, 'opcount opcodes storage size')

opdefs = {
    'cpy2': opdef(2, (1, 2), 0, 4),
    'cpy1': opdef(2, (1, 2), 0, 2),
    'cpy4': opdef(2, (11, 12), 0, 8),
}
```

Now you can address these with `opdefs[token[0]].opcount`, `opdefs[token[0]].size`, etc. This would already be far more readable. You can use the names to define your entries if you find that easier to read:

```
opdefs = {
    'cpy2': opdef(opcount=2, opcodes=(1, 2), storage=0, size=4),
    # ...
}
```

You *could* get away with omitting the `opcount` argument, and just use `len(opdefs[token[0]].opcodes)`.

Next, you could use constants to denote the various options you have. For `storage` you could use:

```
S_NONE, S_DEST, S_SOURCE = range(3)
```

for example, then use those names throughout:

```
opdefs = {
    'cpy2': opdef(opcount=2, opcodes=(1, 2), storage=S_NONE, size=4),
    # ...
}
```

Because we use a separate tuple for the opcodes, you just loop over those:

```
operands=opdefs[tokens[0]].opcodes
for operandnum, opcode in enumerate(operands, 1):
    if opcode == 1: #dest register
        destreg(tokens[operandnum]) #count times register is loaded
```

Comment: yes thanks - a bit better, and i guess if i pulled out the opcode to start with, i.e. opcode=tokens[0] it would clean it up more.

Comment: thanks again.  certainly helps though it still feels like write-only code.  It even caught a couple of places where I had the wrong number of codes in the table.